# How to reset tuleap admin password from backend?

Tags: tuleap

How would I reset the 'admin' user password from backend. I have the shell access to the Tuleap installation, and to the mysql backend database. In the current situation, I am unable to use the 'lost password' link as the email is not still setup properly on the Tuleap.

I have attempted the following but does not seem to work:

I have used /usr/share/tuleap/tools/utils/password_hasher.php to generate a password. Setting the password via mysql:

```
use tuleap;
update user set password='hased-password-from-password-hasher' where user_name='admin';
commit;
```

With that, I am not able to login as 'admin' to Tuleap.
One thing I have noticed is that on every call to password_hasher.php with the same password, it seems to be adding a random salt and generating the hash. Perhaps, I am missing some other update in the above steps?

Searching for this lead me to a mailing list answer that points to use the password_haser.php and update the 'user' table, but I do not have further information.

Comment: Same issue here. Would you perchance also have LDAP authentication active? I'm wondering whether this could be blocking admin access with a local (hashed) password.

Answer (score 1):

1. As root, open `/usr/share/tuleap/src/common/User/User.class.php` in your text editor
2. Scroll down all the way to the bottom of the file
3. Arrange for method `doesUserHaveSuperUserPermissionDelegation` to always return true, e.g.

   ```
       protected function doesUserHaveSuperUserPermissionDelegation()
       {
           return true;  // XXX
           return $this->getPermissionManager()->doesUserHavePermission($this, new SiteAdministratorPermission());
       }
   ```

   Then save the file
4. Navigate to https://tuleap/admin and perform any required changes through the UI
5. Once your work is done, don't forget to undo step 3